# Specify frame size of the embed window Google Sites for HTML highlighted syntax

Tags: html, embed, dimensions, google-sites

I am trying to display code examples in a Google Sites page. When I paste the HTML code using the built-in embed function, it is displayed in a "large" window and I cannot find a way to make it smaller.   The only way I can think is to specify the exact measure using the  tag, however, I do not know how to make it work with the original highlighted code, which is shown below:

```
<!-- HTML generated using hilite.me --><div style="background: #f8f8f8; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><table><tr><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">1</pre></td><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">print <span style="color: #BA2121">&#39;hello world!&#39;</span>
```

```html
<!-- HTML generated using hilite.me --><div style="background: #f8f8f8; overflow:auto;width:auto;border:solid gray;border-width:.1em .1em .1em .8em;padding:.2em .6em;"><table><tr><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">1</pre></td><td><pre style="margin: 0; line-height: 125%">print <span style="color: #BA2121">&#39;hello world!&#39;</span>
</pre></td></tr></table></div>
```

So, how can I specify dimensions of a highlighted syntax code?

Answer (score 1):

I'm assuming that this is the new Google Sites. Well if I embed your original code, I can then re-size the 'embed' window as illustrated in the screen shot below. Does this not work for you?[image]